# Link to meta sometimes doesn't appear on user page

Tags: support, status-bydesign, meta, profile-page

This is the screenshot of my user page:

[image]

Which obviously doesn't contain the link to its meta site whereas the meta site contains the link to the main site.

[image]

This is the third time I am typing this post. Before submitting I go to my user page to double check only to find that the problem does not appear anymore. That's why before this I discarded my post twice.

[image]

So what's the reason behind the link getting disappeared? And why does it reappear without any visible reason?

I am using Windows 10 v1903, Firefox v67. I think my connection is stable enough and I don't think I have any plugins enabled that could raise an error. I haven't hidden any profiles.

The reason could be that this is the first time I visited meta. In fact, I just checked it on another Stack Exchange site and it turns out to be true.

Comment: Was that the first time you visited meta? I expect meta profiles aren't created until you've visited.

Comment: @Kevin You may be correct, at least for some cases of where the Meta button isn't showing. I joined 8 new sites, 7 with meta sites (including this one), over a period of a few days about a week ago. None of the sites initially had the Meta button. However, I manually changed the URL to go to the corresponding meta site for each of those 7 sites. I found that sometime later, with the amount of time varying, the Meta button appeared. The button has now always been visible on every site each time I've checked these sites since then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't create meta profiles for users until they actually go to meta. So, if you've never visited, you'll not have a link to the profile, since it doesn't exist!

Once you visit (assuming you're logged in), it should always be there.

Similar question was asked previously on [our main meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306819/profile-page-on-some-sites-dont-show-link-to-meta-user-page).